# Regex over multiple lines

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code:

```
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<tag 1>(.*?)</tag 1>").matcher(buffer);
  int nr = 0;
  while (matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println("Match no. " + ++nr + ": '" + matcher.group() + "'");
  }
```

Where buffer is:

```
  <tag 1>

     My Value

  </tag 1>
```

How can I enable multiline match for my regex, so I can match this buffer? Thanks!

Comment: Don't do that.  Use an HTML or XML parser.

Comment: As far as parsers go jsoup (http://jsoup.org/) is excellent, especially if you like css selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DOTALL flag in order to make DOT match newlines:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?s)<tag 1>(.*?)</tag 1>").matcher(buffer);
```

OR else:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<tag 1>(.*?)</tag 1>", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

But let me caution that parsing HTML/XML using regex is not the greatest idea.

Comment: Or use `Pattern.compile("<tag 1>(.*?)</tag 1>", Pattern.DOTALL)`